# PK Insert in Oracle (similar to --- SET IDENTITY_INSERT table on, in SQL Server)

Tags: oracle, primary-key, identity-column

In SQL Server it requires certain option to be ON to insert value in `ID` column – `SET IDENTITY_INSERT table ON`.

Could someone help me with the Oracle equivalent? Or will Oracle allow ID value to be inserted by default?

What should we replace `SET IDENTITY_INSERT table ON/OFF` with in Oracle?

Comment: Which Oracle version are you using? And how did you define the primary key? Please **[edit]** your question and add the complete `CREATE TABLE` statement for the table in question.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle 12c finally introduced a proper notion of identity columns (instead of having to manually manage a sequence). Instead of turning it on or off as you in SQL Server, you can just define the table that way:

```sql
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    id NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY
    -- other columns you need...
)
```